# Selecting larger value in 2 timestamp columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Code I am currently using:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

F.when((df.UPDAT_DT.cast("long") - df.CREAT_DT.cast("long")) >= 0,
                           df.UPDAT_DT).otherwise(df.CREAT_DT).alias('DT')
```

`UPDAT_DT` and `CREAT_DT` are timestamp columns

I started with `datediff` but I wanted to check at second level.

Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sicne both columns are of timestamp types you should be able to directly use `<=` and `>=` directly, there is no need to convert them.

In other words, you can do:

```
F.when(df.UPDAT_DT >= df.CREAT_DT, df.UPDAT_DT).otherwise(df.CREAT_DT).alias('DT')
```

You can also use the [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest) function since you just want the max value:

```
F.greatest(df.CREAT_DT, df.UPDAT_DT).alias('DT')
```